# Google Search Console API is returning no data

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-search-api, google-search-console

I am getting empty data when trying to query the data.

Request Params:

```
{
  "startDate": "2021-07-24",
  "endDate": "2021-10-04",
  "aggregationType": "AUTO",
  "dataState": "ALL",
  "rowLimit": 20,
  "searchType": "WEB"
}
```

Response:

```
{
  "rows": [
    {
      "clicks": 0,
      "impressions": 0,
      "ctr": 0,
      "position": 0
    }
  ],
  "responseAggregationType": "byProperty"
}
```

In the Search Console I can clearly see the amount of clicks and impressions but why I am receiving zero data for this timeframe?
I also checked the domain properties and they are the same.

Answer (score 2):

I used the wrong "siteUrl" for the query. When trying to get your data from a "example.com" domain (without www. in front), your siteUrl is sc-domain:example.com.

Comment: Hi! I'm having the same problem, could you please clarify this answer? I don't understand how you fixed it. All my code works fine on 3rd level domain but when I use a 4level one it returns aggregate: bypage

Comment: thanks for the answer! In addition to that my timeframe did not contain any data (did check for yesterday until today around midnight...)